# How to merge multi level datasets and repeat country-year observations?

Tags: r, merge, hierarchical-data, rep

I have a survey data frame with individual-level observations. I want to merge this data frame with another data frame with country-level variables (one row per country-year). This latter should repeat the rows according to the number of rows in the individual-level data frame. I have been tried this using the `rep()` function but it didn't work. I don't know if I was clear, but I would thank you so much if anyone can help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: `?merge`, in base R, or one of the join functions in the tidyverse (e.g. `?dplyr::full_join`, is probably what you want.  If you provide a reproducible example someone can write an answer with a little more detail.